# Как работать с числами с плавающей запятой в С#?

Tags: c#, double

Есть вот такой код простого конвертера валют. (**SOM** - это валюта Кыргызстана)

```
using System;

namespace modConvertUSDRU
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Введите 1 если USD/SOM или 2 если SOM/USD");

            double ENTER = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (ENTER)
            {
                case 1:
                    ConvrtRUUSD();
                break;

                case 2:
                    ConverUSDRU();
                break;
            }
        }

        static void ConverUSDRU()
        {
            double convertUSRU;

            Console.WriteLine("Введите сумму в сомах: ");
            double RU = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Введите курс USD: ");
            double USD = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            convertUSRU = RU / USD;
            Console.WriteLine("Сумма равна {0} $.", convertUSRU);
        }

        static void ConvrtRUUSD()
        {
            double convertUSRU;

            Console.WriteLine("Введите сумму в USD: ");
            double USDSUM = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Введите курс USD: ");
            double USDK = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            convertUSRU = USDSUM * USDK;
            Console.WriteLine("Сумма равна {0} сом.", convertUSRU);
        }
    }
}
```

на красоту не смотрим это просто пример!

**вопрос в следующим:**
***Почему при вводе к примеру (16000) все работает при вводе (16,000) тоже, а вот при вводе (16.000) выдаёт вот такую ошибку***

> Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>     at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
>     at modConvertUSDRU.Program.ConverUSDRU() in D:\MailCloud\C#\CS2017WORK\modConvertUSDRU\Program.cs:line 32
>     at modConvertUSDRU.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\MailCloud\C#\CS2017WORK\modConvertUSDRU\Program.cs:line 20*

Я понимаю что конфликт может быть в каком-то исключении или дело в конфликте (string/double) предположения есть, но где ошибка понять не могу!

Comment: Switch работает с целыми числами.

Comment: Проблема в том, что в одной стране принято писать числа с точной, а в другой с запятой. C# это тоже учитывает и он не засунет значение с точкой к примеру в `es` культуру, либо значение с запятой в `en` культуру.

Comment: Ну я попробовал исключить Switch, но результат тот же! На точку выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: j. Atisto ошибка не самом switch. Просто надо запомнить, что работает с целыми числами.

Comment: Спасибо! Запомню! Ну так а, ошибка где!?

Comment: j. Atisto    @EvgeniyZ написал в комментариях на вверху. Прочтите.

Comment: Но мне нужно было что бы при любом варианте результат был одинаковым. В этом и была ошибка. Но спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Попробую через try cache решить!

Comment: *>>что бы при любом варианте результат был одинаковым* пиши везде `Convert.ToDouble( Console.ReadLine().Replace('.', ',') );`

Comment: Мне кажется если вы хотите что бы любой вариант работал, придется парсить число как строку при помощи, регулярок например, как строку и венять символ с обратной конвертацией в число

Comment: Alias Спасибо! Как раз такой способ решил использовать! Только не как не мог понять где! Спасибо!

Comment: РАБОТАЕТ!!! Спасибо всем за ответы!

Comment: @j.Atisto не торопись, попробуй и поймёшь :) удач.

Comment: @ Alias Спасибо! Знания вроде есть а, как пользоваться, не научился ещё! Так что дерзаю!

Comment: Кстати,  у double слишком маленькая точность и неприятные особенности округления. Для работы с деньгами стоит использовать decimal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ваша проблема заключается в том, что определенные страны имеют свои стандарты. К примеру Америка, у них футы, мили и прочие для нас неведомые показатели. У нас принято все считать в метрах, километрах и других стандартных для нас величин.

Как не странно, но и принятые стандарты в написание чисел тоже у многих стран разные. Где то принято разделять число запятой (123,456), а где то для этого используется точка (123.456). Язык C# в этом плане тоже еще тот любитель все сверять с культурой и в связи с этим, он не даст вам перевести значение с точкой к примеру с `ES` культурой (ну или с `EN` культурой не удастся перевести значение с запятой.).

**Пару примеров:**

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en");
Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("123.456"));
Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("123,456"));
```

Значение с точкой отобразилось правильно, а вот значение с запятой саму `,` попросту откинул и выдал `123456`.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es");
Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("123.456"));
Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("123,456"));
```

Тут у нас значение с точкой - саму точку теряет (123456), а значение с запятой отображается как надо.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ru");
Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("123.456"));
Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("123,456"));
```

А в этом варианте мы получим ошибку `System.FormatException: "Входная строка имела неверный формат."` (на строке с точкой), ибо русская культура не воспринимает точку.

**Так как быть в таком случае, если надо и то и то значение вытащить?**

1. Можем указать культуру явно:

   ```
   CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en");
   Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("123.456", culture));
   ```
2. Можно попробовать предварительно указать культуру и у нашего `string` значения заменять один знак на другой:

   ```
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ru");
   Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("123.456".Replace(".", ",")));
   Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("123,456"));
   ```
3. Можно попробовать воспользоваться таким велосипедом (вызов будет `GetDouble("123,456", 0)`, 0 - значение, если нечего не вышло перевести)):

   ```
   public static double GetDouble(string value, double defaultValue)
   {
       //Пробуем получить значение в текущей культуре
       if (!double.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out var result) &&
           //Пробуем получить в en культуре
           !double.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), out result) &&
           //Пробуем получить в нейтральной культуре
           !double.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out result))
       {
           result = defaultValue; //Значение, если нечего не вышло
       }

       return result;
   }
   ```
4. Еще как вариант, это задавать значение `NumberDecimalSeparator`, которое собственно и отвечает за то, какой символ используется в культуре:

   ```
   var clone = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
   clone.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

   Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("123.456", clone));
   Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("123,456"));

   //Или
   NumberFormatInfo format = new NumberFormatInfo {NumberDecimalSeparator = "."};
   Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("123.456", format));
   Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("123,456"));
   ```

В общем, пробуйте. Удачи!

Comment: А где самый простой вариант - передавать нужную культуру в double.Parse?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Я думаю это очевидный вариант, но вы правы, сейчас добавлю.

Comment: Сделал так: ' double RU = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine().Replace('.', ','));
' Dc` всё отлично работает!

Comment: А, можно написать условие   (** если  (вызывается метод (Console.ReadLine())) {тогда .Replace('.', ',') } **) ну как это написать в операторе if ?

Comment: "Самый очевидный вариант" - правильный, поместите его в начало списка. Запятая в en является разделителем разрядов, поэтому их может быть вообще несколько в строке: `double.Parse("100,200,500.5", new CultureInfo("en"))`

Comment: @j.Atisto Мне кажется вы не правильно пытаетесь решить задачу. `Console.ReadLine()` отдает вам `string`, который потом вам и нужно разбирать, узнавать что в нем, как в нем и тд.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да, я понимаю! Я имел в виду можно ли как нибудь написать условие с таким смыслом.Ну там с помощью конвертации или ещё чего. И почему вариант 'Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine().Replace('.', ','))' не рассматриваться как правильный? Он же работает?

Comment: @j.Atisto Если работает как надо, то почему бы и нет. Что касается форматирования - это символ на `Ё`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо!

Comment: За использование `Replace` в подобных случаях я бы руки отрывал. Культур-мультур на вас не хватает!

Comment: @j.Atisto: `.Replace('.', ',')` — **очень** плохо. Потому что запятая является валидным разделителем тысяч в английской локали. Почему делать неправильно, когда можно делать правильно?

Comment: Господа, ну давайте посмотрим на эту задачу со стороны автора. Создается приложение для себя, либо узкого круга людей, в Америку данная программа вряд ли когда либо дойдет. Что касается ру сегмента, то у нас такое ооочень редко встретишь, я за свои 24 года формат `111,222,333.4` видео только один раз. Да, `Replace` может быть не совсем верно работает с подобным форматом, но задачу автора выполнит на 100% ибо повторюсь, я не думаю, что у него подобное будет.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov >Культур-мультур на вас не хватает! Сам то таким не был что ли. Помогать нужно людям.  @VladD спасибо за пояснение. В конкретном примере мне нужно было сделать, что бы при любой раскладке клавиатуры (с права цифры) результат был одинаковым. Правильно или не правильно это не про данный пример. А, выше перечисленные примеры я тоже попробую. И для себя решу какой не больше нравиться или какой правильный когда пойму их до конца. Пока что вариант вот этот мне понятней. `Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine().Replace('.', ','))` А, самое главное он работает!!!.

Comment: Отдельное спасибо за поддержку! @EvgeniyZ Спасибо!